# Select Other Column Values Along With min(salary) where there can be duplicates of salary

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following schema and data in Oracle datbase.

```
CREATE TABLE people ( 
  person_id   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  title       VARCHAR2(20), 
  salary  INT 
);

INSERT INTO people (person_id, title, salary) 
  WITH names AS ( 
    SELECT 4, 'Prof', 5    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5, 'Prof', 6   FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6, 'Dr',7 FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7, 'Dr',7     FROM dual 
  ) 
  SELECT * FROM names;



  select * from people;
```

I want the id of the least earning person by title and the amount they are earning. If there are two least earning people, I want only one of them. So following is the result I want.

```
Id title Salary
4 Prof 5
6 Dr   7
```

The second row can be `7 Dr 7` also since both Dr s are earning the same amount.
I checked the solutions with [self joins](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/), but it doesn't fit my case where there can be two Drs earning the same amount.

I am using oracle, and suspect maybe the [`FIRST`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions065.htm#SQLRF00641) function can help me here? But I couldn't find a place where this is explained well enough for me to understand.

Fiddle with data available [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/567db5/3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH T AS
  (SELECT person_id,
          title,
          salary,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY title
                             ORDER BY salary,
                                      person_id) minsalary
   FROM people)
SELECT person_id,
       title,
       salary
FROM T
WHERE minsalary = 1
ORDER BY 1
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/567db5/4)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `FIRST` aggregate function.

Refer [FIRST](http://%20https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm) for detailed explanation.

```
SELECT MIN(person_id) KEEP (
        DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY salary
        ) AS id
    ,title
    ,MIN(salary) AS salary
FROM people
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY id;
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c265/3)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain how it works. Basically I don't understand how MAX(person_id) would return the id of the person with the lowest salary in that group (same for MAX(salary)? And what does `KEEP` and `DESNE_RANK` mean?